# Slope/direction field interpretation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am starting a course in differential equations and started learning the concept of direction (or slope) fields and integral (or solution) curves. So the direction field for a first order ODE in the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$$ is a set of small line segments in the $xy$-plane, where the line in some point $(x_0,y_0)$ has a slope $f(x_0,y_0)$. The integral curve is defined as a curve that has the same direction as the direction field at every point (it is tangent to the slope field everywhere). These integral curves represent the solutions to the differential equation, since if the curve is some $y(x)$, (assuming $y(x_0)=y_0$) the slope of that curve at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ evaluated at that point. I understand all of this, but I have some trouble with the different interpretations of the slope field.

The first interpretation is that each point $(x_0,y_0)$ has some "associated slope" $f(x_0,y_0)$. (I personally don't understand the meaning of "each point has an associated slope")

Another is that the slope at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ has to coincide with the slope of the solution (integral curve) at that point.

Is there a better and more intuitive interpretation of what the slope field actually *represents*? Thanks in advance